# Si Performer Soundcraft 2 Recording Main output L&R

Tags: audio-recording, live-sound

I am doing sound for a musical at our school in exactly 6 days, and we are planning on recording it.

But last year when they recorded the annual musical, we used direct output from mixbus 6 and took audio from there, and as we went through the musical, sound would differentiate in the recording, because we would make the L&R Mains sound good, but the recording did not sound good beacause adjusting volume would not affect the mixbus 6.

Is there a way to link mixbus 3 (our new recording output) and Main, so that all changes to the main will also affect what we are recording? Or a way to record the Main directly?

Here is a picture of our soundboard and the back:

[image: Soundboard]

[image: Back]

I see that there are outputs saying 'Aux' (little blurry), and if it actually says that, would it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth scanning the manual to see which aux sends can be switched between pre- & post-fader, then use one of those, set post. That way your fader levels will directly affect your aux levels, as though in series.

This will also let you compensate for such as live drums, which would maybe be turned down a bit to FoH because you can hear them in the room, but would let you push them a bit in the aux send, so the right mix is going to 'tape'.